# Select all non-special principals using SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need to make a list of all non-special user accounts retrieved from an SQL Server 2008 database. I can run this query:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.server_principals WHERE is_disabled <> 1 AND type = 'S';
```

But the result still includes principals such as `sa`.

Any idea how to do it?

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu: SQL_LOGIN

Comment: You mention database principals in the question, but look at server principals in the query. Which are you interested in?

Comment: @EdHarper: My bad. Corrected. It must be server-wide login principals.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I think I got it:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.server_principals WHERE
is_disabled <> 1 AND
type = 'S' AND
IS_SRVROLEMEMBER('sysadmin', [name]) = 0
```